# Better FGLRX driver for Radeon HD 8570M

Tags: drivers, ati, fglrx

My new laptop computer uses a AMD APU with the Radeon HD 8570M Graphics chip. By default, the X.org open source driver is used. Even though it is working, I still prefer the offered proprietary driver (2:13.350.1-0ubuntu2).

The open source driver seems to let the chip consume more power and only supports OpenGL 3.0 (Mesa 10....). Using the proprietary AMD Catalyst driver lets the battery last longer, and uses OpenGL 4.3, but it makes it impossible to change the screen brightness. As I am currently developing a game using OpenGL (as a paper for school) I would like to use a rather current version of it.

Is there any newer version of fglrx which supports OpenGL 4.3 (maximum the 8570M supports) AND lets me change the display brightness? I once tried the beta fglrx from AMD's support website, but it screwed up my system and I had to reinstall.

However, I don't have the time to perform a full reinstall again at this moment. Is there any way I may undo the problems a installation of a non-working driver may bring (e.g. no GUI) (like switching back to xserver-xorg-video-ati from command line as the Driver Manager does)

Comment: did you used `xserver-xorg-video-radeon` driver?

Comment: The Driver Manager ony offers me `xserver-xorg-video-ati`, but it is installed. How do I enable `...-radeon`?

Comment: try with `sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-ati && sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon`

Comment: Ad if it's already installed?

Comment: `...ati` and `...radeon` are defferent isnt it? [See](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=xserver-xorg-video&searchon=names)

Comment: Yes, but despite BOTH are installed, only `...ati` , `fglrx` and `fglrx-updates` (latter ones same version) are displayed in the Driver Manager. I'd assume `...radeon` is incompatible with my card.

Comment: @the_Seppi  Have you tried the xorg-edgers or oibaf repositories?  I don't think either support OpenGL4.3, but they do support more than the standard xorg drivers.

Comment: Could make an answer out of it? (with an instruction or a link to one on how to revert the changed from command line)

Comment: Also note the [APU Turbo Boost aspect of using `fglrx`](http://askubuntu.com/a/502392/308343).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I switched from xserver-xorg-video-ati to fglrx (to get Minecraft shaders to work) and it worked! I can change the screen brightness.

I think this is due to the latest updates, but I don't even remeber what updates I installed in the last few weeks...