# how do I enable AMD Turbo Core the cpu on my acer aspire 7560?

Tags: acer, amd-processor, cpufreq, turbo-boost

I have an acer aspire 7560 that on windows supported (through acer proprietary software) boosting the cpu from 1.9ghz to up to 2.5ghz for long periods of time so long as there was adequate cooling. On ubuntu, I get a top speed of 1.9ghz no matter what I do. I am not trying to overclock past what it is supposed to go, but basically how would I go about doing this? I have googled everywhere and everyone recommends using the bios and that if there isn't an option there it can't be done. I know it can, I know it can be done and still be stable on this computer, and I know that it is possible to do through simple software. My processor is an AMD Fusion A8-3520M quad-core 64 bit processor with integrated radeon graphics and 4gb of ram. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you overclock the processor in BIOS. and it's not always that easy. This is most likely off topic since it's not really about Ubuntu...

Comment: I have to use ubuntu, when it was running windows it would automatically boost it. there is NO OPTION in the bios to change it, it just did it automatically

Comment: and it is about ubuntu as I am trying to figure out how to overclock with ubuntu. Sorry I have to ask, but did you read the question fully?

Comment: did you read my comment fully? jupiter supports processor down clock (on some cpu). You can try that, search the site for it. But it's not simple software to overclock the processor. it's normally done in the BIOS, but then it's only a stable overclock, like alwyas running at 2.3 GHZ. if you want boost then you need to have unlocked multiple (mine is at 34 (34*100 mhz = 3.4ghz ish.) but that's rare on laptops.

Comment: what are you talking about? what is jupiter in that context and wait...what?

Comment: jupiter is a program (search the site). I'm trying to tell you that it's not a simple program to overclock the processor, which might explain why you can't find it for Ubuntu...

Comment: I was just pointed at this website yesterday (https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/boost.txt) which discusses boost and AMD.

Comment: I'll check it out and report back my finding

Comment: so basically it is impossible currently to do it explicitly but is enabled by default. I want to know how I could change the parameters to at least influence it. My system is plugged in 24/7 in an air conditioned room, I have no real worries about power consumption. Thanks for the link and I'll look around elsewhere. however, I did at one point find a forum where people were discussing that there was a cpu init file that controlled the cpu speed, or some firmware area that was writable. I'll try and find it

Comment: I just looked and found something about the "fsb"

Comment: @sbergeron You can safely forget about init files and firmware areas. Much of the information found on the web regarding Turbo Boost is pretty outdated, both in terms of the used software and the hardware. Most people discussing this on forums do not even correctly figure out which tools will never display boost info. Even these days, they file bugs in this regard. If MS Windows can boost your A8, Linux can do it, too. However, [for AMD APUs such as the A8, there seem to be (at least)two bugs](http://askubuntu.com/a/502392/308343).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Update 2015]**

Starting with Linux 3.16:

- The value for `bapm` can be provided as a module parameter (see [here](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/attachment.cgi?id=145411&action=diff)).
- The value of `bapm` is set to 1 by default for Kaveri, Kabini and desktop Trinity, Richland systems (see [here](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dri-devel/2014-July/062841.html)), resulting in Turbo Core being enabled.

Which means that with Kernel 3.16 or later, Turbo Core *should* work right out of the box with `radeon` in many cases.

If you run Debian, or if you run Ubuntu and the above is not true for you, please refer to [How to set up a Debian system (focus on 2D or console/server) with an AMD Turbo Core APU for maximum energy and computing efficiency?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/241825/79761)

**[Update 2014-Aug-07]**

I published a [detailed analysis over at `unix-stackexchange.com`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148918/79761) which contains (at least for me) a few surprises. Such as the `ondemand` governor potentially being worse than `performance` (at least with the Richland A10-6700) and `fglrx` apparently using some questionable tricks to improve short-term boosts, abruptly having to compensate for that in the long run. I'm glad I had a closer look at this.

**[Original Answer]**

AMD Turbo Core is supposed to be enabled by default in all current Linux versions.

Turbo Core, however, is a feature available on AMD CPUs *with* and *without* integrated GPU. And there seem to be two issues regarding those *with* an integrated GPU. Your A8 falls into this category.

- If the kernel does not have the ATI/AMD 'fglrx' module loaded, the APUs appear to stick to the non-boost/regular frequencies. I presume that the reason is that Turbo Core is a decision made by the APU itself, based on several criteria such as power dissipation/TDP. It seems that the GPU on the chip will not contribute to the decision unless it gets initialised properly. And properly here means that you must use the official dirver; not even the free `radeon`will do the trick. I have [filed a bug report over at kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=81021) but the question remains whether it will be easy to have the kernel initialise the GPU just for the sake of the boost (if my assumption about the root cause is correct).
- However, even [with `fglrx`, there appears to be a bug if you intend to use Dynamic Power Management](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=78111).

For a bit more of explanation e.g. about which tools correctly identify boosts, [see here](https://askubuntu.com/a/501599/308343).

Comment: All of that is nice and dandy, but OP has Llano. Bidirectional APM [didn't exist](http://www.anandtech.com/show/5831/amd-trinity-review-a10-4600m-a-new-hope/2) there. Perhaps the GPU [could](http://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=42648#c6) still influence the CPU headroom ([pm](http://github.com/torvalds/linux/commit/80ea2c129c) only came in [3.13](http://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/dri-devel/2013-November/048316.html)) but maybe he was just running 12.04 LTS (no version was mentioned) and missing out the 2012 cpufreq rework. Or [nothing is wrong](http://askubuntu.com/a/501846) already.